# SASS - Output separate stylesheets for page templates

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, sass, gruntjs

Trying to understand the best practice for structuring my sass underscores project.

I have a basic working environment using npm and grunt, and get my main css compiled, but i want to create multiple page templates in a sub folder, and have their respective .scss file be output in a /layout folder so that i can enqueue the separate page template stylesheets as .css after the main stylesheet in function.php

i structured my project files in roughly this order: // updated //

```
.gitignore
404.php
archive.php
comments.php
/compiled
    style-human.css // Readable CSS Before prefixing //
    style.css // Minified CSS Before Prefixing //
    /page-layouts
        page-frontage.human.css // Readable page-template CSS before prefixing //
        page-frontage.css // minified page-template CSS before prefixing //
/fonts
footer.php
functions.php
gruntfile.js
header.php
/inc
index.php
/js
/languages
/node_modules
package.json
/page-layouts
    page-frontage.css // prefixed minified CSS to be Enqueued after main style.css in functions.php //
    page-frontage-human.css // prefixed readable CSS //
/page-templates
    page-frontpage.php

page.php
rtl.css
/sass
    _normalize.scss
    /elements
    /forms
    /layout
        _footer
        _header
        /page-layouts
            _page-frontpage.scss 
    /media
    /mixins
    /modules
    /navigation
    /site
    style.css // @imports everything SCSS except page-layouts //
    /variables-site
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style-human.css // readable main stylesheet //
style.css // minified main stylesheet Enqueued in functions.php //
/template-parts
```

This is the code i used in my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /**
        * sass task
        */
        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                  style: 'expanded',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {
                 'compiled/style-human.css': 'sass/style.scss'   
                }
        }, 
        dist: {
                options: {
                  style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {
                 'compiled/style.css': 'sass/style.scss'   
                }
            }
        },

        /**
        * Autoprefixer
        */
        autoprefixer: {
          options: {
           browsers: ['last 2 versions']
          },
            // prefix all files //
            multiple_files: {
             expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: 'compiled/*.css',
                dest: ''
            }
        },

        /**
        * Watch task
        */
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*scss',
                tasks: ['sass','autoprefixer']    
        }
    }

    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Now i have tried a couple of different solutions but I'm nowhere near to understand how i should structure my gruntfile.js so that it outputs my two page-templates scss as auto prefixed css in the layout folder.

Comment: Doe's your actual code do anything?

Comment: Right now it takes my style.scss and compile it into a regular  human readable style-human.css and a minified style.css and puts them into a /compiled folder, and then runs autoprefixer on those files and put them in the root of my theme file.

Comment: I basically want it to keep doing that, and also take my /page-template scss files and repeat the procedure witch compiling and prefixing those files and in the end put them into a /page templates folder so that i can enqueue them after my main main style.css in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Sort of managed to find a workable solution, probably not the most elegant one, but it works, sort of...

I structured my files like this:

```
.gitignore
404.php
archive.php
comments.php
/compiled
    style-human.css //-- Readable CSS Before prefixing --//
    style.css //-- Minified CSS Before Prefixing --//
    /page-layouts
        frontage.human.css //-- Readable page-template CSS before prefixing --//
        frontage.css //-- minified page-template CSS before prefixing --//
/fonts
footer.php
functions.php
gruntfile.js
header.php
/inc
index.php
/js
/languages
/node_modules
package.json
/page-layouts
    frontage.css //-- prefixed minified CSS to be Enqueued after main style.css in functions.php --//
    frontage-human.css //-- prefixed readable CSS --//
/page-templates
    frontage.php //-- code for template goes here, Enqueued in functions.php --//
page.php
rtl.css
/sass
    _normalize.scss
    /elements
    /forms
    /layout
        _footer
        _header
        /page-layouts //-- working folder for all page templates --//
            _frontpage.scss //-- SASS for page template goes here! --//
    /media
    /mixins
    /modules
    /navigation
    /page-templates
        frontpage.scss //-- @imports content of ../layout/page-layouts/_frontpage.scss --//
    /site
    style.css //-- @imports everything SCSS except /page-layouts --//
    /variables-site
search.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style-human.css //-- readable main stylesheet --//
style.css //-- minified main stylesheet Enqueued in functions.php --//
/template-parts
```

And i structured my Gruntfile.js as follows

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /**
        * sass task
        */
        sass: {                // Task
            dev: {             // Target
                options: {     // Target options
                  style: 'expanded',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {       // Dictionary of files
                 'compiled/style-human.css': 'sass/style.scss', // 'destination': 'source'
                    'compiled/page-layouts/frontpage-human.css': 'sass/page-templates/frontpage.scss'   // 'destination': 'source'
                }
        }, 
        dist: {             // Target
                options: {  // Target options
                  style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {       // Dictionary of files
                 'compiled/style.css': 'sass/style.scss',   // 'destination': 'source'
                    'compiled/page-layouts/frontpage.css': 'sass/page-templates/frontpage.scss' // 'destination': 'source'

                }
            }
        },  // close sass task

        /**
        * Autoprefixer
        */
        autoprefixer: {
          options: {
           browsers: ['last 2 versions']
          },
            // prefix all files //
            multiple_files: {
             expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: 'compiled/*.css',
                dest: ''
            },
            // prefix frontpage template //
            multiple_files: {
             expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: 'compiled/page-layouts/*.css',
                dest: './page-layouts'
            },
        },

        /**
        * Watch task
        */
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*scss',
                tasks: ['sass','autoprefixer']    
        }
    }

    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Basically this works how i intended it to, the page-template stylesheets get saved as  human readable/minified autoprefixed versions in the intended page-layouts folder, so that i can Enqueue them after the main style.css in functions.php

Only one "small" issue left to work out, my page-template scss files does not understand variables...

Comment: Got it to work as intended. Problem was that i @imported the files in wrong order in my frontage.scss file, of course i have to first import the variables-site.scss and mixing-site.scss before i import my page-template file using variables and mixins...

Answer (score 0):

For what I see, your default task only launch the watch task, who will only launch the sass and autoprefixer task if a scss file is updated.

You should use :

```
grunt.registerTask('default',['sass','autoprefixer']);
```

In practice, we don't place the watch task into the default task, because it stop the thread. We call the watch task instead, once the server is started. (use the command `grunt watch` in a terminal at the same level of your gruntfile)

Comment: Im not sure I'm following you? i want the watch task to run and watch for .scss updates when i run grunt, and as it stood up until today when really started messing with my Gruntfile.js, it did what i wanted, which was, anytime i changed something in my scss files, it updated and autoprefixed two stylesheets, style-human.css and style.css.
what is the exact difference with your suggestion?